# Exporting a Greenplum data base to Amazon S3 as a .csv

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-s3, etl, greenplum

Hypothetical scenario - I have a 10 node Greenplum cluster with 100 TB of data in 1000 tables that needs to be offloaded to S3 for reasons. Ideally, the final result is a .csv file that corresponds to each table in the database.

I have three possible approaches, each with positives and negatives.

COPY - There is a question that already answers the how, but the problem with psql COPY in a distributed architecture, is it all has to go through the master, creating a bottleneck for the movement of 100TB of data.

gpcrondump - This would create 10 files per table and the format is TAB Delimited, which would require some post-gpcrondump ETL to unite the files into a single .csv, but it takes full advantage of the distributed architecture and automatically logs successful/failed transfers.

EWT - Takes advantage of the distributed architecture and writes each table to a single file without holding it in local memory until the full file is built, yet will probably be the most complicated of the scripts to write because you need to implement the ETL, you can't do it separately, after the dump.

All the options are going to have different issues with table locks as we move through the database and figuring out which tables failed so we can re-address them for a complete data transfer.

Which approach would you use and why?

Comment: You don't want to use gpcrondump - you end up with files which not only hold the data in COPY format, but also with additional SQL statements which are required to restore the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use the S3 protocol.

http://www.pivotalguru.com/?p=1503

http://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/43160/admin_guide/load/topics/g-s3-protocol.html

Comment: After looking at the links, it appears that you are recommending building the External Writable Tables. I think that is where I was leaning and the links provide some clarification on finer points. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, external writable tables but specifically, write it to s3 directly.